# How to limit the column width for the html tabular data that is rendered from xml that has xsl as reference

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>RTCP STUB STATUS</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32" >
<th>Stub Component</th>
<th>Stub Name</th>
<th>Stub Operation</th>
<th>Stub Version</th>
<th>Stub Status</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="//stub">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@component" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@operation" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@version" /></td>
<td><xsl:for-each select="instances/instance">
<xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
<xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</td> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now when i run the XML that has this above xsl as reference , the tabular html output is perfectly obtained , but for few rows where the component name is too long the screen becomes scroll able from left to right and its not good to navigate and scroll that way.
I would very much appreciate if someone could let me know how to limit the column size for the rendered html output. my first column Component itself covers the whole screen from left to right.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some style rules for formatting that table to your outputted html.  Add a style sheet to your html like so (I have not shown any irrelevant parts of your stylesheet)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}
            td {width: 20%; word-wrap: break-word;}
        </style>
   </head>
   <body>
```

These additional style rules cause the table to fill the window and each cell to be 20% of the window width (you can adjust this as needed).  Words that are too long to fit in the cell are broken/wrapped to the next line.

Comment: how do we decide the color of the generated output text in xsl based on condition, say for example:- <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="@status='RUNNING'">
                                                 <xsl:color>green</xsl:color>
          </xsl:when></xsl:choose>    Here xsl:color doesn't work..any suggestions. Because i need to decide the color for the output text based on whether that text value is Running or Deploying or Stopping,etc

Comment: You can use a CSS class.  Change `<td>` in your style sheet to `<td class="{@status}">` and add to the end of that css stylesheet above (after `td {width: 20%; word-wrap: break-word;}`) the line `td.RUNNING {color: green;}`.

Comment: Could you please let me know where exactly to use :- Change <td> in your style sheet to <td class="{@status}"> You could refer my original xsl file above and then let me know the additional changes.  requirement is that:- <td><xsl:for-each select="instances/instance">
<xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
<xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</td> Here whenever status column displays value as Running it should be in green color if its Stopping it should be Red and likewise

Comment: @Ashley If you need more detail, you should post a new question.  It is off-topic for an answer to this question, and I can't really post a full answer in the comments due to space and formatting restrictions.  If you post a new question about the coloring, I'll try to answer it, provided nobody beats me to it.  Be sure to add the changes to your stylesheet that you got from this answer to the stylesheet in the new question.

Comment: Question posted here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622740/choose-text-color-for-outputted-html-rendered-tabular-data-through-xml-with-xsl