# Choose text color for outputted html rendered tabular data through xml with xsl as reference

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
    table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}
    td {width: 20%; word-wrap: break-word;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>RTCP STUB STATUS</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32" >
<th>Stub Component</th>
<th>Stub Name</th>
<th>Stub Operation</th>
<th>Stub Version</th>
<th>Stub Status</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="//stub">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@component" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@operation" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="@version" /></td>
<td><xsl:for-each select="instances/instance">
<xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
<xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</td> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on my above xsl, i just want to make sure that whenever the value for status column for my output tabular data is Running its displayed in green color, if its Stopping it gets displayed as red. How do i add that part to this above xsl. I tried several ways to do this but none worked. It seems xsl has its own way to display output text pertaining to color.
Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Sample XML

```
<stubs> 
    <stub component="ChannelInquiry_Binding_HTTP_v2" name="getAllChannelAvailabilityStub" operation="getAllChannelAvailability" version="26.7"> 
        <instances>
            <instance status="STOPPING"/> 
        </instances> 
    </stub>
<stubs>
```

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample of your XML, please? Also, can you should one of the ways you tried? Note that XSL has no concept of colour. All it is doing is outputing HTML (and CSS) and that handles the colour. So, ideally you would want to know what the HTML + CSS is expected to look like before you did the XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: a part of the xml is:-

Comment: You should edit your question to show your XML (There is a small "edit" link just under the list of tags) as XML in comments is hard to read. Thanks!

Comment: <stubs>                                                                                                   <stub component="ChannelInquiry_Binding_HTTP_v2" name="getAllChannelAvailabilityStub" operation="getAllChannelAvailability" version="26.7">
<instances>
<instance status="STOPPING"/>
</instances>
</stub>                                                                                                         <stubs>

Comment: This is just a part of the xml but it explains the xsl i provided in the original question. All i need is that for every status that is being selected i get the output html data for that values are say RUNNING or STOPPING ,etc. so these status values under STUB Status column that i get after running the xml in browser should be green or red respectively. i couldn't figure out any way to include this part of formatting in my xsl. if its possible using additional css or html code pls let me know where to include that in my xsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a class to each of your rows to be styled, and then add the appropriate rules to the stylesheet.

If you wish to set the color of the entire row, change the first line of

```
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@component" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@operation" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@version" /></td>
    <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="instances/instance">
            <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
</tr>
```

to `<tr class="{./instances/instance/@status}">`.  This will add the status as a class attribute to your outputted table rows.

Now you can modify the css stylesheet to

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}
    td {width: 20%; word-wrap: break-word;}
    tr.Running {color: green;}
    tr.Stopping {color: red;}
</style>
```

---

If instead of coloring the entire row, you wish just to color the status column, instead of the above, you need to change the first line of

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="instances/instance">
        <xsl:value-of select="@status"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

to `<td class="{./instances/instance/@status}">` and modify the css stylesheet to

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}
    td {width: 20%; word-wrap: break-word;}
    td.Running {color: green;}
    td.Stopping {color: red;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but then i get the same output there is no change in color.. RUNNING is displayed in same default black color.

Comment: @Ashley fixed it.  The lines to be modified were not selecting the status correctly.

Comment: Perfect you rocked yet again. It works like a charm.:)